# Nodejs Q promise catch never called with passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using the passport library for node to assist me in user signup. I'm also using the 'Q' promise library to avoid the pyramid of doom as I go through several asynchronous steps.

Everything works fine, until I throw an error from one of the promised steps. I would have assumed execution would drop into the `.fail` function, where I could handle the error and return out of passport with a failed signup. But for a reason that I don't understand, the `.fail` function never gets called. Instead, I just get a stackdump in my browser window and in my console.

The controlling code is here:

```
q.fcall(checkEmailIsFree({'email':email, 'username':username, 'password':password}))
.then(checkUsernameIsFree)
.then(registerUser)
.then(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    logDebug('REGISTERED: ' + email);
    return done(null, user);
  }
  else {
    logDebug('Could not register');
    return done(null, false);
  }
})
.fail(function (err) {
  logError('I never get here');
  return done(null, false);
})
.done();
```

And here's how I'm throwing, from within `checkEmailIsFree`

```
var error = new Error('Bad times. Email is in use: ' + email);
throw error;
```

Is there some overall express / node code somewhere that is set to fast dump out an exception somehow? Why isn't my catch being called? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think [`done(onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress)`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress) can help in this case. You can try:

```
q.fcall(checkEmailIsFree({'email':email, 'username':username, 'password':password}))
.then(checkUsernameIsFree)
.then(registerUser)
.then(function (user) {
  if (user) {
    logDebug('REGISTERED: ' + email);
    return done(null, user);
  }
  else {
    logDebug('Could not register');
    return done(null, false);
  }
})
.done(undefined, function (err) {
  logError('Error!'); // used in case of reject
  return done(null, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but alas this isn't working for me.

It's worth saying - the server doesn't crash when an Error is thrown, it just prints a stack trace and then sits idle.

Comment: Aha, I realise if I don't `throw`, but instead `q.defer().reject()`, then the .done clause gets called. I can work with this, but I'd still like to understand the mechanics around `throw`

Comment: Actually I should have mentioned that. You need to reject a promise for it to properly handle the condition.